# Calculating speed from a Pandas Dataframe with Time, X, and Y columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm trying to calculate speed between consecutive timepoints given data that is in a '.csv' file with the following columns: "Time Elapsed", "x", and "y". The ultimate goal is to get the data into a format where I can plot "Time Elapsed" vs. "speed"

I'm fairly sure that my implementation is doing what I want, but it's certainly possible (and likely) that I overlooked something. I'm also wondering whether there are faster/more efficient ways (in Python) to perform these calculations?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def calculate_speeds(path_to_csv):
    data_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)

    xy = data_df[['x', 'y']]

    b = np.roll(xy, -1, axis=0)[:-1]
    a = xy[:-1]
    dxy = np.linalg.norm(a - b, axis=1)   

    dt = (np.roll(data_df['Time Elapsed'], -1) - data_df['Time Elapsed'])[:-1]

    speeds = np.divide(dxy, dt)

    speed_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Time Elapsed':data_df['Time Elapsed'][:-1],'Speed':speeds})

    return speed_df
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code reads good enough and is pretty straightforward; you should consider improving its quality by adding documentation in the form of a docstring explaining what kind of data it expects. Speaking as such, you should extract the I/O part out of the function and have it being fed the required data, for better reusability and testing.

One other thing to note is that you perform the same `roll` twice on different columns of the same dataframe. You can combine these operations and write the equation in a more ... equationy-ish way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def calculate_speeds(positions_over_time):
    time = 'Time Elapsed'

    movements_over_timesteps = (
        np.roll(positions_over_time, -1, axis=0)
        - positions_over_time)[:-1]

    speeds = np.sqrt(
        movements_over_timesteps.x ** 2 +
        movements_over_timesteps.y ** 2
    ) / movements_over_timesteps[time]

    return pd.DataFrame({
        time: positions_over_time[time][:-1],
        'Speed': speeds,
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_df = pd.read_csv(path_to_csv)
    calculate_speeds(data_df)
```

Comment: +1, in the OP's code it took me quite some time to find the actual velocity calculation, because it is split and partially hidden behind the `np.linalg.norm`...